# How do we connect to only Primary Set when connected to MongoDB replica set using connection string?

Tags: mongodb

We configured MongoDB replica set in Ubuntu server with two secondary set.
When we try to connect to replica set via mongo shell. It is connecting to secondary.
We should make sure that it should only connected to Primary set.
connection string we tried:
mongo 'mongodb://publicIP1:27017,publicIP2:27017,publicIP3:27017/?replcaSet=rs123'

Comment: Are you sure? Because `primary` should be the default, see [Read Preference Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html#read-preference-options)

Comment: Now the behaviour is like
when publicIP1 is primary and is in first place, in string
it is connecting to Primary

when secondary set is n first place in string, then it is connecting to seconday

Comment: as far as I remember (but I don't have evidence at hand), mongo shell always checks 27017 port, so if 27017 is not a primary now, it will be connected to the secondary

Comment: The proof: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#local-mongodb-instance-on-default-port

Comment: If its connected to secondary, we cannot do any write operations to database ?

Comment: @kokkondanagaraj yes. You can check rs status via: `rs.status()` (section `members`)

Comment: @dododo but he specified the port for each host - and it's the default 27017 anyway for all.

Comment: You misspelled replica in the URI option.

Comment: @D.SM is right...

Comment: what will be the correct string for replica set to connect only to primary set ?

Comment: @dododo
if we don't have write operations, connectig to secondary from mongo shell is not a good thing..........

Comment: @kokkondanagaraj, not sure that I understand you, write operation can be done only from the primary, but you can read from the secondary if you configure it. AFAIK, the shell is mostly used for development, so I think it means you can use it in whatever way you need to

Answer (score 0):

See this doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/. The connection string will look like: `"mongodb://localhost?readPreference=primary"`